# Deleting Site Columns and Content Types Programmatically

Tags: content-type, site-column, feature-receiver

I have a feature that adds two site columns to a content type on activation. On deactivation it's supposed to delete them, but I'm getting the following error:
"Site columns which are included in content types or on lists cannot be deleted. Please remove all instances of this site column prior to deleting it."

```
        SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
        SPContentType cType = web.ContentTypes[Constants.ClientContentTypeName];

        cType.FieldLinks.Delete(Constants.DebtMgmtClientID);
        cType.FieldLinks.Delete(Constants.DebtMgmtCompanyID);
        cType.Update();

        web.Fields.Delete(Constants.DebtMgmtClientID); // This line throws the error
        web.Fields.Delete(Constants.DebtMgmtCompanyID);
```

I guess I'm doing it in the wrong order. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this SP2010 or 2007?

Comment: Is it possible that another list or content type is using these site columns?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the Column from every content type that may be using it. For example: If you created a column, and bound it to the `Document` content type, and pushed it down to all of its children, you'll need to remove it from every one of those children before deleting the custom column.